# AutoGenerate SubscriberKey

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is there a way to autogenerate the SubscriberKey? I want some mechanism by which I can generate a unique no. automatically.

Please suggest

Comment: What's the use-case?  If you'll provide more details about where and why you need to generate it, the community can provide you something more useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [GUID()](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#guid) function in AMPScript or [NewID()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx) in a [Query Activity](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/).

You'll have to manually assign it.

Comment: Hi Adam, I am getting my subscribers from an external system.. Using API, we'll insert into all subscribers..

Comment: If that's the case, then why not specify the SubscriberKey in your API call?  You have to specify them.  The SFMC platform doesn't automatically assign them.

Comment: Yes I can do that.. But how do I know that the one I am generating doesn't already exist in SFMC

Comment: You'll either have to do a retrieve first to check or trap the error.